# Divisibility (algebra, number theory).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Suppose you have

$$a b c = m$$

$$a|y$$
$$b|y$$
$$c|y$$

Does that imply that

### $$m|y$$

$$am_1 = y$$
$$bm_2 = y$$
$$cm_3 = y$$

$$mm_1 m_2 m_3 = y^3$$

??

Comment: I took the dots out of the  multiplication in the first equation.

Answer (score 2):

No. Try $a=b=c=y=2$.

If $a,b,c$ are coprime, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

$$a|y $$ $$b|y $$ $$c|y$$ imply $$\text {lcm}(a, b, c)|y$$ but not $$abc|y $$